# ByPass proxy using HttpURLConnection on jboss webapp

Tags: java, jboss, httpurlconnection, http-proxy

I have a `webapp1` deployed on jboss4 that enable proxy using `System.setProperty`.

Now i deployed onother webapp (`webapp2`) on the same jboss where i need to run an http request without using the proxy.
For the http client i'm using `java.net.HttpURLConnection`

Is it possible?